# How to reset field setProtection in Java

Tags: java, reset, protected

I cant reset protection to one field.

Hello,

screenControl is a class, which makes sense in connection with  a screen.
setProtection is a method of the ScreenControl class. The setProtection method expects the
corresponding editor instance, i.e. the field providers, as well as the field to be protected as either the field as a string
or type-safe as a TypedField instance. The last parameter of the setProtection method is a value of the type boolean
that determines whether the field protection should be activated or deactivated.

import de.abas.erp.axi.screen.ScreenControl;

**With this code I protect all fields:**

screenControl.setProtection(head, true);

**After that I want to reset protection of one field. I use this code, but it doesn`t work. **

screenControl.setProtection(head, field, false);

Comment: What is screenControl? You need to add more information to your question and ideally some more code including your imports, class and methods

Comment: ScreenControl is a classs, which makes sense in connection with a screen.